# Fill dynamically sized array in C++ and use the values

Tags: c, memory-management, arrays

I'd like to fill a char-array dynamically and check whether the contained values are valid integers, here's what I got so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == ',')
        {
            commaIndex = i;
        }
    }
```

commaIndex is the index of a comma inside a file, numerical values should have been entered before a comma, file looks like this: -44,5,19,-3,13,(etc), it's important for this part:

```
char *tempNumber = new char[commaIndex];
```

Fill tempNumber (which should presumably be just as big as the number due to my dynamic allocation) so I don't have a number in a size 50000 char-array (named input).

```
for(int i = 0; i < commaIndex; i++)
    {
            cout << i << "\n";
            tempNumber[i] = input[i];
    }
```

And now I want to use it:

```
if(!isValidInteger(tempNumber))
    {
        cout << "ERROR!\n";
    }
```

Unfortunately, tempNumber always seems to be of size 4 irregardless of the value of "commaIndex", i.e. I get the following output:

(Inputdata: 50000,3,-4)

commaIndex: 5
content of tempNumber: 5000 (one 0 missing)

commaIndex: 1
content of tempNumber: 3²²² (notice the 3 ^2s)

commaIndex: 2
content of tempNumber: -4²²

Any ideas?

One more thing: This is for a homework assignment and I am not allowed to use any object-oriented element of C++ (this includes strings and vectors, I've been there and I know it would be *SO* easy.)

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: I'm also not allowed to use that unfortunately, I've been there. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Slap your teacher, this is just stupid. You should only not be allowed to use `std::vector` and similar when *reimplementing them for learning purposes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by the [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) function.

Comment: Yes, I might be, and I already was, but I forgot to add: this is for a homework assignment and I'm not allowed to use strings or any object-oriented implementation of C++ for this. Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: Notice that `strtol` does not use `std::string` but wraps the standard C function of the same name.

Comment: @DennisRöttger That means you are asking about C, not C++.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, I'm new to C/C++, I'll update my question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Objects (thru `class`) and `template`-s are at heart of C++;

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can make my teacher accept strtol, works like a charm with this, and I suddenly have a much weaker urge to vomit when I see the state of my code without being able to use vectors and strings. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider using `strtok()` with `sscanf()`. Notice, that `strtol()` does not allow you to check for errors since it simply returns (perfectly valid) value `0` on parse error. On the other hand, `sscanf()` returns number of successfully read items, so you may easily check if there was an error while reading a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "1,2,-3,+4,a6,6";

    /* calculate result table size and alloc */
    int max = 1;
    char* tmp = str;
    while (*tmp)
        if (*tmp++ == ',')
            ++max;

    int* nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * max);

    /* tokenize string by , and extract numbers */
    char* pch = strtok(str, ",");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(pch, "%d", &nums[i++]) == 0)
            printf("Not a number: %s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    /* print read numbers */
    for (i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);

    free(nums);

    return 0;
}
```